# Convert IEnumerable to another IEnumerable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

Coming from JS/PHP/Node background, somewhat new to C# app dev. Working on an ASP.NET MVC app.

I need to return an object of `IEnumerable<Car>` to my controller from my service. My service calls my repository which returns `IEnumerable<CarEntity>`.

I cannot figure out how to convert a list of `CarEntity` to a list of `Car`.

`Car` looks like

```
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarColor { get; set; }
    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
```

and `CarEntity` looks like

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProp { get; set;}
```

This is an example but this is generally what I need. Do I need to do some sort of loop through my `CarEntity` list and push each one to the `Car` list? I would think there's some more astute way of doing this.

Comment: or your car entity can just inherit car

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need to create a new `Car` object for each item in the car entity list collection and assign property values. You can do that in a foreach loop

```
var carEntityList= new List<CarEntity>(); //assume this has items
var carList = new List<Car>();
foreach(car carEntity in carEntityList)
{
  var c= new Car();
  c.CarId =carEntity.Id;
  // to do : Map other property values as well.
  carList.Add(c);     
}
```

**Or** Using handy LINQ extension methods such as [`IEnumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var carEntityList= new List<CarEntity>(); //assume this has items
var carList = carEntityList.Select(s=>new Car { 
                                                CarId = s.Id, 
                                                CarColor = s.Color, 
                                                CarModel = s.Model,
                                                CarMake = s.Make
                                              }
                                  );
```

Comment: As an aside, if you frequently need to make Cars from CarEntities, a constructor to Car that accepts CarEntity simplifies things greatly, and has less possibility of error.

Comment: Thanks for putting both ways, should have mentioned I am using LINQ. Using LINQ, if both the input and output happened to have the same exact properties, would I be able to set carList = carEntityList, or would I still have to convert? And if I have to convert, is there a shortcut when the properties are typed and named identically? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: You cannot do that because both are different type collections. You will get a compile time error saying that collectionX cannot be converted to collectionY!. So you need to do this create object-set property values thing. If you are using LINQ, simply use the `Select` extension method as i have shown in the second part of the answer.

Comment: This is almost a meta question: What are your thoughts on answering the question with `ToList()` on the end of your code? On the one hand the user may be clueless and therefore safer to always put `ToList()` so their results are materialized on this line of code instead of on the line that ends up using the results, on the other hand maybe we should assume they know how LINQ works. There are already 5 answers with `Select()` and one of them decided to use `ToList()` but none of the others did. Pedantic, or important to point out to the asker?

Comment: Apparently a lot of editors here have no idea how C# or Linq works. Your answer has a typo where it sets the fields of a `CarEntity` (`ID`, `Color`, `Make`, `Model`) and when trying to create a new `Car`. They should be `CarID`, `CarColor`, `CarMake` and `CarModel` when making a `Car`.

Answer (score 2):

The long hand way is using LINQ's [.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` to [*project*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/04/22/projection-2/) one the items from one collection into another:

```
IEnumerable<CarEntity> carEntities = repository.GetCars();

IEnumerable<Car> cars = 
    carEntities
    .Select(c => 
         new Car
         {
             CarId = c.Id,
             CarColor = c.Color,
             //etc.
         });
```

There are tools out there like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), but I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `results` is `IEnumerable<CarEntity>`:

```
 IEnumerable<Car> cars = results.Select(c=> new Car{Brand = c.Brand, Color = c.Color});
```

Comment: I think you meant IEnumerable? (Since Stack won't let third parties (easily) edit typos...)

Answer (score 1):

Another Linq centric solution if you do a lot of `CarEntity` to `Car` mappings would be to create an implicit conversion and use Cast<>:

```
public static implicit operator Car(CarEntity aCE) {
    return new Car() { CarId = aCE.Id, CarColor = aCE.Color,
        CarMake = aCE.Make, CarModel = aCE.Model };
}
```

and then you could just

```
List<Car> cars = carEntities.Cast<Car>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Car> cars = results.Select(r=> new Car(){CarId = r.Id, CarColor = r.Color .... etc}}).ToList();
```

`results` would be your IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quiet simple
lets assume your collections as follow

```
IEnumerable<Car>=cars;
IEnumerable<CarEntity>=entities;
```

then your code should run on all entities like this:

```
foreach(CarEntity e in entities){
       Car c = new Car(e.Id,e.Color,e.Make,e.Model);
       cars.Add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to input, if you have lot's of entities and you need (possibly should) convert them to other boundary objects for different uses, I would put that mapping logic in an extension class for the entities.

This is to not put a dependency on the entity - and possible other database or other specific dependencies related to persistence past the boundary of the persistence layer.
Also it gives you a nice place to check all your mapping rules - easy to test and change, and you get to make nice context specific models that implement what they need for their contexts, like this Car class that appends the word "horses" to the horsepower property.

I created this little example showing this:

```
public class CarRepository
{
    private readonly SqlCarStore _carStore;

    public CarRepository(SqlCarStore carStore)
    {
        _carStore = carStore;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Car> GetCars()
    {
        IEnumerable<CarEntity> dbCars = _carStore.GetCars();
        return dbCars.Select(c => c.ToCar());

    }
}
public static class CarEntityExtensions
{
    //Maps from CarEntity to Car
    public static Car ToCar(this CarEntity entityCar)
    {
        return new Car
        {
            Make = entityCar.Make,
            Model = entityCar.Model,
            Year = entityCar.Year,
            HorsePower = entityCar.HorsePower.ToString(),

        };
    }
}
public class CarEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    private string _horsePower;
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string HorsePower
    {
        get { return _horsePower; }
        set { _horsePower = $"{value} horses"; }
    }
}
```